# Why cannot all statements be annotated in Java?

Tags: java, annotations, element

I ran into a simple issue naively trying to do this:

```
public void someMethod(){    
  int x = 0;
  ...
  @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
  x = ((Comparable)lhs).compareTo(rhs);
  ...
}
```

This is illegal and has to be rephrased to compile:

```
public void someMethod(){  
  ...  
  @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
  int x = ((Comparable)lhs).compareTo(rhs);
  ...
}
```

I have traced the issue down to [ElementType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html) : a statement doesn't seem to be a valid program element. This is rather confusing - I thought that a statements is something like a supertype of all programming elements.

1. Is there a theoretical or a technical reason for the restriction of valid elements?
2. Could it be done differently - i.e. supposed I could supplant `ElementType` with my own class and master the rippling changes, could I annotate any statement?

Comment: It's not at all clear what the context is here. It doesn't help that you haven't actually specified the annotation. Really, what are you trying to do?

Comment: What I was trying to do and have done was to suppress some compiler warnings. What I am trying to do now is to understand the deeper reason why I cannot annotate random statements. I am not very good at the theory of programming languages, but this seemingly arbitrary restriction intrigued me

Comment: So please show the *complete context*. Are you trying to do this within a method, or declaring an instance variable, etc?

Comment: @Jon I am trying to do this in a method, annotation a local variable. Have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Right. The edit makes this considerably clearer, although indenting it would help too...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you look at [the Javadoc for `@SuppressWarnings`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) you'll see the answer: its declared targets are

```
@Target(value={TYPE,FIELD,METHOD,PARAMETER,CONSTRUCTOR,LOCAL_VARIABLE})
```

In other words, *it cannot be legally applied to a statement.* It can, however, be applied to a variable declaration. It has nothing to do with whether a statement is a program element; it is basically because this annotation applies only to declarations of things.

Furthermore, if you look at [the Javadoc for the enumeration that describes things that can have annotations,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html) statements and expressions are not among the choices. In general, annotations can be applied to declarations of things, not to bits of code.

The theoretical reason for this is just that annotations are stored as properties of individual items declared in the class file. Statements don't qualify; by the time your code is compiled, statements have ceased to exist. There is only a stream of bytecode, and the only reminder of the statements it came from are the (optional) line number tables. To deal with this, they'd need to add a new attribute to the class file to reference the individual bytecodes, as in [this proposal,](http://code.google.com/p/jsr308-langtools/wiki/AnnotationsOnStatements#New_Class_File_Attributes) and deal with a number of complexities that arise as a result.

Comment: Thank you, Ernest. I am aware of the specification. The question already has a link to ElementType. I wanted to know, WHY the decision was taken to restrict annotations to declarations.

Comment: As a former member of JSR-308 expert group, I have to down vote this for the last paragraph containing several invalid statements and largely author's own speculations, especially around "line number only" part.

Comment: He he. You will have to remove all statements with the "only" word to make it believable. :)

Answer (score 5):

I know an answer has already been accepted, just throwing this out there. Here's an excerpt from the FAQ for [JSR-175](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr175/index.html) which originally added annotations to Java:

> **Why can't you annotate arbitrary program elements such as blocks and individual statements?**
>
> This would greatly complicate the annotation syntax: We would have to sacrifice the simplicity of saying that annotations are simply modifiers, which can be used on declarations.

In other words, because it's too much work :-)

Comment: Nice one, makes me reconsider the accepted answer since this one's from the horse's mouth. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It [has been proposed](http://code.google.com/p/jsr308-langtools/wiki/AnnotationsOnStatements) as part of [JSR-308](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=308) to allow annotations on statements, but currently it is not supported and won't be part of the next Java language release (i.e. Java 8).

I guess that at the time annotations been added to the language, the main target class and method level information mainly crafted around run-time use cases (e.g. Java EE, JPA, JAX-WS, etc), while statement-level annotations are primarily useful at compile-time (see above link to the wiki for the list of use cases).

Comment: Thanks for the references, Eugene. Looking forward to the JSR-308 then :)

Answer (score 2):

A declaration in Java is an entity that has an identifier and can be referenced from other parts of the program. A statement doesn't meet that criteria - it's an action that possibly results in a value being assigned to some declared entity.

Section 6.1 of the Java spec (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/names.html#6.1) lists the types of declarations, which aligns with the `ElementType` enumeration values.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. The second sentence makes it a bit more clear to me - a statement cannot be refenced. Bit why is referencing important here? The statement has it's place in the syntax tree and can be reached by traversal, so it could be accessed otherwise...

Comment: @kostja Not sure. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that annotations are often used at run-time to get information about program elements through reflection. As far as I know, there's no way to use reflection to access statements in a program.